# Space-Time Principal Component Analysis with Missing Lat/Long Data

Tags: r, pca, missing-data, data-imputation, spatio-temporal

Thank you for your help,

I am looking to run a space-time Principal Component Analysis on Shotspotter data from Brockton, MA: http://justicetechlab.org/data/. Shotspotter sensors record the timing, location, and number of gunshots. There are gaps in the data when no shots were detected.

I would like to include the gaps in my PCA. At the temporal scale of a day, I have filled in the gaps and assigned a value of zero rounds to days when there were no gunshots detected (e.g. row six of the table below).

[image: row 6 is an example of]

I am confused about how to handle the missing lat/lon data for these zero shots-fired days. When there are no shots detected, there are no shots detected *everywhere*, so assigning a lat/lon seems strange. But I would like to include the zero shots detected data points.

Statistically speaking, would the best solution be to? :

```
 1. ignore the zero data completely
 2. use the mean lat/lon for the observed data
 3. randomly generate lat/lon data within the region of study and substitute these for missing lat/lon
 4. use another statistical method well suited to my problem - any suggestions would be much appreciated
```

I have found some papers on how to impute missing measurements, but have not found much explaining how to handle missing lat/lon data:

http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/members/dray/files/articles/dray2015a.pdf
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7bf7/e383847e7d29134f95894b463de731fd4c1d.pdf

Thanks again for your time and feedback